# I have created a scrollbar for my website, I can scroll using my mouse pointer, I want to scroll it using my mouse also

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have created a scrollbar for my website, I can scroll using my mouse pointer now I want to scroll it using my mouse also please help me.

```
    <div class="scrollbar"></div>

    <div class="scrollable">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras non nunc eget sapien molestie mollis. Proin vestibulum vehicula varius. Duis a nunc ac risus facilisis consectetur. Nullam ornare pulvinar felis, in malesuada nulla fringilla eget. Suspendisse bibendum aliquet nulla, ac laoreet eros mattis at. Nunc tempus leo et sapien volutpat placerat. Nam eget urna nulla. Mauris sed mi mauris. Cras posuere aliquet enim a rhoncus. Donec sed vulputate velit. Morbi bibendum, ipsum eget elementum lacinia, neque justo iaculis orci, non lacinia erat diam vitae augue. Duis et arcu in augue bibendum fermentum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras non nunc eget sapien molestie mollis. Proin vestibulum vehicula varius. Duis a nunc ac risus facilisis consectetur. Nullam ornare pulvinar felis, in malesuada nulla fringilla eget. Suspendisse bibendum aliquet nulla, ac laoreet eros mattis at. Nunc tempus leo et sapien volutpat placerat. Nam eget urna nulla. Mauris sed mi mauris. Cras posuere aliquet enim a rhoncus. Donec sed vulputate velit. Morbi bibendum, ipsum eget elementum lacinia, neque justo iaculis orci, non lacinia erat diam vitae augue. Duis et arcu in augue bibendum fermentum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras non nunc eget sapien molestie mollis. Proin vestibulum vehicula varius. Duis a nunc ac risus facilisis consectetur. Nullam ornare pulvinar felis, in malesuada nulla fringilla eget. Suspendisse bibendum aliquet nulla, ac laoreet eros mattis at. Nunc tempus leo et sapien volutpat placerat. Nam eget urna nulla. Mauris sed mi mauris.
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my JavaScript, I want it to scroll using mouse wheel.

```
<script>
var parH = $('.parent').outerHeight(true);
var areaH = $('.scrollable').outerHeight(true);
var scrH = parH / (areaH/parH);

function dragging(){     
    var scrPos = $('.scrollbar').position().top;   
    $('.scrollable').css({top: -(scrPos*(areaH/parH)-1)});
}
$('.scrollbar').height(scrH);
$('.scrollbar').draggable({
    axis: 'y',
    containment: 'parent',    
    drag: function() {
         dragging()
    }

});
</script>
```

and this my css

```
<style>
.parent{
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    width:180px;
    background:#eee;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-right:17px;
}
.scrollable{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;        
    width:180px;
    background:#cf5;
}
.scrollbar{
    cursor:n-resize;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    z-index:2;
    background:#444;
    width:17px;
    border-radius:8px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Can't get you. Can you please give a clear description?

Comment: What is the difference between scrolling with your mouse and your mouse pointer?

Comment: Are you trying to scroll by holding the click ? Like we would do on mobile or tablet ?

Comment: Why have a callback function with only a callback in it: `drag: function(){ dragging() }`. This would have the same affect: `drag: dragging()`.

Comment: sorry sorry , I mean mouse wheel